# separate numerical and categorical variable in pandas datframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a huge list of data in spark, and I took its headers only and saved in in the pandas dataframe.

Now I want to make different list out of it to separate categorical and numerical

```
df2 = df.dtypes
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
print(df3)
```

`df4= df3.filter(df3[1] = 'String')`

this statemnet gives error:

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: I think you missed another `=` sign there. Shouldn't it be `df3[1] == 'String'` ?

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava : Thnak you very much.
if you got my question , can you please help me separate all those columns in a separate list which has string data type.
Please help if it is two lines of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Here we can get the categorial and numerical data separated**

Let's consider Kaggle's Ames Housing dataset.

**Step 1: Load the required libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

**Step 2: Load the dataset**

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("C:/datasets/train.csv")
```

**Step 3: Separate numeric and categorical variables**

```
numeric_data = dataset.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
categorical_data = dataset.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number])

numeric_data.shape[1]
categorical_data.shape[1]
```

There are 38 numeric and 43 categorical columns in the dataset.

Answer (score 3):

you can get non numeric columns from dataframe like this

```py
df.loc[:,df.dtypes==np.object]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Pandas, use pySpark [dataframe.describe()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.describe) to find all **numeric** and **string** columns (this will skip columns types like *date*, *timestamp*, *array*, *struct* etc.) and then filter out *StringType()* columns using information from df.dtypes:

```
from datetime import datetime
df = spark.createDataFrame([ (1, 12.3, 1.5, 'test', 13.23, datetime(2019,9,23)) ], ['i1', 'd2', 'f3', 's4', 'd5', 'dt'])
# DataFrame[i1: bigint, d2: double, f3: double, s4: string, d5: double, dt: timestamp]

# find all numeric and string columns from df (remove the first column which is `summary`)
cols = df.limit(100).describe().columns[1:]
# ['i1', 'd2', 'f3', 's4', 'd5'] 

# get a mapping of column vs dtypes of the df:
dtype_mapping = dict(df.dtypes)
#{'d2': 'double',
# 'd5': 'double',
# 'dt': 'timestamp',
# 'f3': 'double',
# 'i1': 'bigint',
# 's4': 'string'}

# filter out string-type from cols using the above mapping:
numeric_cols = [ c for c in cols if dtype_mapping[c] != 'string' ]
# ['i1', 'd2', 'f3', 'd5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with that necessary another '=', you are missing a few things, like the index you are trying to access is '0' not '1'. Also, there is no data type 'String' in pandas DataFrame, it is 'object'. You may try something like this:

```
df2 = df.dtypes
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
print(df3)
df4 = df3.filter(df3.iloc[:,0] == 'object')
```

Comment: I have SQL Data frame  in spark which is actually a hive table.
This table has multiple columns like string and integers, Now I want to create two different lists one will store all the String data types while the other will store all integer data types.

  0  1
0  Employee   string
1  Age           int